# Input box value coming as undefined

Tags: jquery

I am getting input box value as undefined when appending to a div. 
Below is the code.

JS:

```
$('#submitHook').click(function () {
    var v = ('#try').val();
    alert(v);
    $('#container').prepend('<tr><td>' + v + '</td></tr>');
});
```

HTML:

```
<code>
<input type="text" id="try"></input>
<input type="button" id="submitHook"></input>

<table id="container></table>
</code>
```

Also how can the same be exteneded to a textarea?
Appreciate any help.

Comment: The HTML supposed to be blank?

Answer (score 5):

You're missing a $ before ('#try')

```
$('#submitHook').click(function(){ 
    var v = $('#try').val();
    alert(v); 
    $('#container').prepend(''+v+''); 
});
```

Comment: thats the same thing I tried.. not working :(
any other workaround..?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `$` sign (the jQuery object). This should work:

```
$('#submitHook').click(function(){ var v = $('#try').val(); alert(v); $('#container').prepend(''+v+''); });
```

You should be able to do exactly the same thing with a textarea too, just reference its ID attribute, like you have done here with `#try`.

Comment: yup.. thats exactly what I did.. however something went wrong in that code when I pasted it here.. 

actual code I tried is : var v = $.('#try').val(); $('#container').prepend('<tr><td>'+v+'</td></tr>');

Comment: It looks as though you've got a `.` character in there that you don't want. Where your code says `$.("#try")` it should read `$("#try")`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to use the jQuery selector ($) when you assign the value to v.

Here's the updated code:

```
$('#submitHook').click(function () {
    var v = ** $. ** ('#try').val();
    alert(v);
    $('#container').prepend('' + v + '');
});
```

Comment: something went wrong in that code tag.. 
actual code is : var v = $.('#try').val(); $('#container').prepend('<tr><td>'+v+'</td></tr>');